# How can I both insulate and get a latch to work on this window? Foam kerf insulation strips

Tags: windows, latches

After trying many options, I've finally found something that might work to reduce drafts and noise through these 1925 historic windows:

[image: MD Foam Kerf Door Insulation Strips on Window]

But that latch.  Original brass, matches the house, but won't work well with the insulation.  Is there a latch style that might be better available in a vintage style?

I went to the foam kerf style because the more modestly size rubber bulb insulation is so stiff it can't make for good compression, given the relatively wimpy single latch on each window.  Sticky foam on the casing similarly failed because the gap ranges from zero to 1/4" or more.  The window swings out on hinges.

[image]

[image]

[image: Tight fit]

Comment: Please include a wider shot of the entire window and casement so we have enough information to make a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a piece of blocking behind the latch and move the latch receiving hole into the kerfed board?  You could paint the blocking black or something that matches the latch hardware.

Comment: Pretty much what I was thinking.

Comment: See new picture above.

Comment: Yeah add the 1/2" thick piece of blocking behind the latch which will pull it forward 1/2".  Then make the latch receiving slot to match in the kerfboard and window jamb.

Comment: The hard part is the receiving slot would be right on top of the plastic retainer for the foam, and on top of the weak slot cut for the retainer.

Comment: That would be true if there was no blocking behind the latch but the new blocking that you put behind the window latch pulls the latch forward into the room putting the new receiving slot in a portion of the new window jamb piece that is sold.